# Pass Javascript Variable to Vue

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

How can i pass a Javascript Variable to a Vue Component?

I have this jQuery function which generates the menu and pushes all the Values inside the array menu:

```
var menu = [];

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.service-desc-wrap h2,.cta-button').each(function(){
        if($(this).hasClass('cta-button')) {
            if($(this).attr('title') && $(this).attr('href')) {
                var linkTitle = $(this).attr('title');
                var href = $(this).attr('href');
                data = [
                    title = linkTitle, 
                    href = href,
                ]
                menu.push(data);
                $('#menu, #menuMobile').append('<a class="menuText" href="'+href+'">'+linkTitle+'</a>')
            };
        } else {
            var tag = $.slugify($(this).text());
            $(this).attr('id',tag);
            var linkTitle = $(this).text();
            if($(this).attr('title')) {
                var linkTitle = $(this).attr('title');
            };
                data = [
                    title = linkTitle, 
                    href = tag,
                ]
                menu.push(data);
            $('#menu, #menuMobile').append('<a class="menuText" href="#'+tag+'">'+linkTitle+'</a>')
        }
    }); 
});
```

I want to pass the array to a Vue Component called

```
<service-menu-component></service-menu-component>
```

The jQuery Function and the Component are inside a blade.php file, i'm using Laravel as a backend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any Vue component has access to the global scope (a.k.a `window` object), in which `$` performs. You don't have to do anything special about it. In simpler words, if a variable has been declared in global scope at the time your Vue component is created - Vue can access it. But Vue won't react to later mutations performed on the contents of that variable. Not out of the box, anyway.

In Vue, that behavior is called *reactivity*. If that's what you want, you could use [`Vue.observable()`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-observable):

- declare a `const`, holding a reactive reference (`store.menu` in this example - name it to whatever makes sense to you)
- use a `computed` in your Vue component, returning the reactive reference
- at any point, (before or after Vue instance's creation) modify the reference from anywhere (including outside Vue component/instance) and the Vue instance will get the change

Proof of concept:

```js
Vue.config.productionTip = false;
Vue.config.devtools = false;
// you don't need the above config, it just suppresses some warnings on SO

// declare store, with whatever contents you want:
const store = Vue.observable({menu: []}); 

// optionally push something to menu:
// works before Vue instance was created
store.menu.push({foo: 'bar'});

$(function() {
  // optionally push something to menu 
  // also works after Vue instance was created - i.e: 3s after $(document).ready()
  setTimeout(function() {
    store.menu.push({boo: 'far'});
  }, 3000)
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  computed: {
    menu() {
      // this injects the store's menu (the reactive property) in your component
      return store.menu
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.12/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <pre v-text="menu"></pre>
</div>
```

The `computed` doesn't have to be on the root Vue element (it can be inside your `<service-menu-component>` component). The above is just a basic implementation, to demo the principle.

Comment: Thanks for the amazing explanation, hats off to you.

Answer (score 0):

Use props:

```
<service-menu-component :data=YOUR_ARRAY></service-menu-component>
```

In the component:

```
props: ['data'] // the data being passed.
```

Comment: The jQuery function and the component are inside a blade template, i can't pass data to the component like that.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, It's possible you need to import this jQuery snippet file to your parent component, and then pass it down to your `service-menu-component`.
Here's how the code should look like:

Your Parent.vue

```
<template>
    <service-menu-component :data=menu></service-menu-component>
</template>
<script src="<pathToYourJqueryFile>"></script>
```

And then in your `service-menu-component`:

```
<template>
   <div>
      {{ menu }}
  </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  name: 'service-menu-component',
  props: {
      menu: {
          type: Array
      }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: The jQuery function and the component are inside a blade template, i can't pass data to the component like that.

Comment: I am not sure then. I have no experience in working with laravel/blade.

Answer (score 0):

What made it work and seemed simple after trying different things is moving the jQuery function inside the component mounted hook like this:

```
    mounted() {
            var menu = [];

            $(document).ready(function(){
                $('.service-desc-wrap h2,.cta-button').each(function(){
                    if($(this).hasClass('cta-button')) {
                        if($(this).attr('title') && $(this).attr('href')) {
                            var linkTitle = $(this).attr('title');
                            var href = $(this).attr('href');
                            data = {
                                'title': linkTitle, 
                                'href': href,
                            }
                            menu.push(data);
                            $('#menu, #menuMobile').append('<a class="menuText ml-2" href="'+href+'">'+linkTitle+'</a>')
                        };
                    } else {
                        var tag = $.slugify($(this).text());
                        $(this).attr('id',tag);
                        var linkTitle = $(this).text();
                        if($(this).attr('title')) {
                            var linkTitle = $(this).attr('title');
                        };
                            var data = {
                                'title': linkTitle, 
                                'href': tag,
                            }
                            menu.push(data);
                        $('#menu, #menuMobile').append('<a class="menuText ml-2" href="#'+tag+'">'+linkTitle+'</a>')
                    }
                });
                console.log(menu);
               
            }); 

             this.menu = menu;
    },
```

It worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

**@Şivam Kuvar** verdiği örnekteki gibi `:data='menu'` yazan yeri `:data="json_encode($controllerdata)"` ile değiştir ve verilerini kullanmaya hazırsın. veri yapına göre `@{{ data.data[0].title }}` olabilir örneğin veya `@{{ data.title }}` bu gelen veriye bağlı dostum.

Just like @Şivam Kuvar's example, replace :data='menu' with :data="json_encode($controllerdata)" and you're ready to use your data. According to the data structure, it can be @{{ data.data[0].title }} for example or @{{ data.title }} it depends on the incoming data, my friend.